# how to push_back vector with no size in a specific location?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I'm trying to get a solid understanding of Vectors. So i understand if we init vectors as following we specify the exact location in array for the vector to exist

```
vector<int> temp[5];
temp[i].push_back(randomInt);(i a random position)
```

but what if i'm trying to have a vector without specified size because i do not know the amount of input? how would i define the first index for example of temp as i did previously using the following init?

`vector<int> temp;`

Comment: Are you asking how to have a unknown number of vectors?  If so, just but the vector into a vector, ie `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`

Comment: @DanielLangr on my end it compiles perfectly but a small change would be that i have ```int V = 5;``` and use V inside the declaration rather than ```5```

Comment: @NathanOliver I'm asking if i can have a unknown size array of vectors

Comment: Just use a vector, instead of an array.

Comment: @NathanOliver i'm trying to implement an adjacency list graph representation and based on what i studied online its best to do it like that?

Comment: @STOPIMACODER If you don't know the size in advance, you may just use a `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`.

Comment: Note that `push_back` inserts a new element at the, ahem, back of the vector.  If you want to insert at a specific location, then use `vector::insert` (this takes an iterator, if you have an index, use `vector.begin()+index`).

Comment: @MartinBonner that i understand but what if i'm trying to have an array of vectors? but i'm not sure about the array size?

Comment: Forget about C-style arrays. For a static array where the size is known, use `std::array`. For a dynamic array where the size is not known, use `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1):

here:

```
vector<int> temp[5];
```

you declared an array of 5 vectors, but going by your description it looks like you're meant to declare one vector with pre-allocated 5 elements (if so, then it should have been like `vector<int> temp(5);`)

> how would i define the first index for example of temp as i did
>   previously using the following init?

all the std containers have methods allowing you to push / emplace data (i.e. to extend them) and method `size()` allowing to check the current size of the container.

Comment: what if i'm trying to have an array of vectors? but not sure what the array size would be?

Comment: then you need to use a vector of vectors: `vector<vector<int>> temp;`